# Number of compositions with exactly $m$ occurrences of $k$

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a closed formula for the number of [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of an integer $n$ (partitions  considering the order of the parts) with exactly $m$ occurrences of an integer $k$ ($k \leq n$)?

For example, the sixteen compositions of $n=5$ are:

```
5
4 + 1
3 + 2
3 + 1 + 1
2 + 3
2 + 2 + 1
2 + 1 + 2
2 + 1 + 1 + 1
1 + 4
1 + 3 + 1
1 + 2 + 2
1 + 2 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 3
1 + 1 + 2 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 2
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1.
```

And the number of compositions that have exactly $m=3$ occurrences of $k=1$ is equal to 4:

```
2 + 1 + 1 + 1
1 + 2 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 2 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 2
```

Unfortunately I am not familiar with generating functions, but perhaps Corollary 2.12 from this paper by [Heubach and Mansur](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Silvia-Heubach/publication/230801389_Compositions_of_n_with_parts_in_a_set/links/0fcfd514729cc55d81000000/Compositions-of-n-with-parts-in-a-set.pdf) could be used to get a closed formula (by setting $A=\mathbb{N}$ and $B=\{k\}$)?

Answer (score 4):

Standard generating function techniques give that the generating function for compositions keeping track of the number of occurrences of every part is

$$\sum_{n \ge 0} \left( w_1 x + w_2 x^2 + \dots \right)^n = \frac{1}{1 - w_1 x - w_2 x^2 - \dots }$$

where $(w_1 x + w_2 x^2 + \dots )^n$ counts compositions with $n$ parts and the exponent of $w_i$ tracks the number of occurrences of the part $i$. The generating function you want is obtained by setting all the $w_i$ equal to $1$ except for $w_k$, which I will rename $w$, which gives

$$\frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{1 - x} + x^k - w x^k} = \frac{1 - x}{1 - 2x + (w - 1)x^k(x - 1)}.$$

The coefficient of $w^m x^n$ is then the number of compositions of $n$ with $m$ occurrences of $k$. There are various other things you can do from here (e.g. compute asymptotics) depending on what exactly counts as a "closed formula" for your purposes. For example, if you want to know what happens when $m, k$ are fixed and $n \to \infty$ then you can extract the coefficient of $w^m$ by rewriting the generating function as

$$\frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{1-x} + x^k} \left( \frac{1}{1 - w \frac{x^k}{1 - \frac{x}{1-x} + x^k}} \right)$$

which lets us recover the coefficient of $w^m$ by expanding the geometric series, giving

$$\frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{1-x} + x^k} \left( \frac{x^k}{1 - \frac{x}{1-x} + x^k} \right)^m = \frac{x^{mk}}{ \left( 1 - \frac{x}{1-x} + x^k \right)^{m+1}}.$$

This can also be proven directly; it amounts to counting compositions with $m$ occurrences of $k$ by removing those occurrences and considering the resulting $(m+1)$-tuple of compositions of numbers adding up to $n - mk$ and not involving $k$. For $m, k$ fixed and $n \to \infty$ this gives the usual rational generating function asymptotics in terms of the smallest root of the denominator.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Sorry for my ignorance on the topic, but how can I use the expression you derived? For example, in the small scenario I mentioned earlier, with $n=5$, $m=3$ and $k=1$, how can I get $4$ as an answer?

Sorry also for not being clear in my question, but by "closed formula" I meant something that could be expressed with summations, binomial coefficients, etc., preferably non-recursive.

Comment: @Lionel: you compute the coefficient of $x^5$ in the last generating function above after setting $m = 3, k = 1$, which is $\frac{x^3}{\left( 1 - \frac{x}{1-x} + x \right)^4} = \frac{x^3(1 - x)^4}{(1 - x - x^2)^4} = x^3 + 4x^5 + 4x^6 + 14x^7 + \dots$. Generally speaking generating functions are more useful than summations, e.g. the generating function tells you immediately (if you're familiar with how rational generating functions work) that for $m = 3$ and $k = 1$ the asymptotic behavior as a function of $n$ is $O \left( n^3 \phi^n \right)$ where $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: If you wanted to you could get a big complicated sum by expanding the generating function out but I promise you that the generating function is more useful. It just depends on what you're trying to do. What do you want to use a "closed form" for?

Answer (score 0):

Even tho Qiaochu gives you a great answer(+1), here is a purely combinatorial one:
Stars and Bars tells you that the number of compositions of $n$ into $s$ parts is given by $\binom{n-1}{s-1}$. Using inclusion-exclusion, you can compute the number of compositions of $n$ into $s$ parts that avoids the occurrence of $k$ by considering the family of sets $A_i=\{\text{compositions of $n$ into $s$ parts such that the $i$-th part is equal to $k$}\}$, so $|A_i|=\binom{(n-k)-1}{(s-1)-1}$ and in general $\left |\bigcap  _{x\in X}A_x\right |=\binom{(n-k\cdot |X|)-1}{(s-|X|)-1}$. This means that the compositions that avoid $k$ are given by $0$ if $n<s$ or if $n\geq s$
$$\sum _{\ell = 0}^s(-1)^{\ell}\binom{s}{\ell}\binom{(n-k\cdot \ell)-1}{(s-\ell)-1}.$$
Now, the number of compsitions of $n$ with exactly $m$ occurrences of $k$ is given by choosing the positions of the $m$ $k$'s and completing the composition with one that avoids $k$. So the formula would be
$$\sum _ {s = m}^n\binom{s}{m}\sum _{\ell = 0}^{s-m}(-1)^{\ell}\binom{s-m}{\ell}\binom{(n-k\cdot ( \ell +m))-1}{(s-m-\ell)-1}.$$
**Edit:** This needs a correcting factor of $(-1)^{n/k-m} \binom{n/k}{m}$ when $k|n$ as the [SAGE script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1U8tO6zAQXTdS_mHUbpLWQQ2wAWEWXIF0vwGxSNMUWbHHlcdB_fw7Eye3VYEskvG8zpyT8QpwcLsugD9A693xRgwEg9EDwbEJkaD58mZv8BP6PNt3BzkXqEj15WOeLQznP5FYi9DFISBsZ6_e_uTWmlviHnqt6-s4EejROPgAlseA0OBnV2wVbeoRbhEjp-wMemcaW2DVr21VK6r4XUqcIZKX4YG7cIStVLtoPUaDQycHoo0uCq5ar225_t-RFJ9ilIzVMbAQxbJ6XiqrxqYCpH6r-mUqGWviSJRnScTY2FtW0SUVYXpm_vNZZKCzDE5hkgGunlGU8b8wsmNc6fs9TShfjOwS0eusxJrUuVeM6rrsovsFN0Seo37IM-fYuMuzvufvfZ5NSv7Ftno9tY-wVEkAVoBH7UUjmslHL2zetyN7c2aPQv4jz8R9Erc1FIs_vLWeTDQeiVPKeSnH4Km8af3AyAyhtXNpg3x8tx0WU0b5sdF1WggarWnWlzDEDt58aDuZl6PlHOMOJayOfG3Ot2dnfdvTP59h538=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) suggests, not sure yet if its from implementation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan After giving it a little more thinking, I don't understand what you mean. Isn't $m+1$ compositions the same as one big composition?  What do you mean that the positions of the $k's$ matter? There are no $k's$ after I fix them with the first binomial.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I understand that they are different, that is taken care by the binomial. I have verified computationally, and when I plug those values I get the correct answer, and I get some more answers right(I checked against bf in the script).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry for insisting, but I have checked up to $n=20$ and the formula is good up when I add up this correcting factor that I am not sure yet if its wrong in paper or code. Also, I forgot to comment that I am saying that $m+1$ compositions are a big composition in the sense that $\prod _i 1/(1-x)^a_i=1/(1-x)^{\sum a_i}$.